# Pass nested pointers of general depth to a function in C

Tags: c, pointers, types, casting, signature

How can I declare a function in C which accepts a nested pointer of a variable depth?

For example, the function should accept `int*` or `int**` or `int***` and so on.

I figure that my function signature will make use of `void`, but I can't work out how to cast back to a pointer of a pointer of ... a type.

Here's a non-general example of what I want to achieve

```
void myfunc(void* obj, int dim) {
    if (dim == 1) {
        int* myobj1 = (int*) obj;
        // do stuff with myobj1

     } else if (dim == 2) {
         int** myobj2 = (int**) obj;
         // do stuff with myobj2
     }

     // ad infinitum
```

Is this at all possible, knowing C is staticly typed?

Comment: Why not have 3 functions, that have the correct type in the signature, and each of them does the appropriate cast to the base int * that is actually required?

Comment: This definitely sounds like an X-Y problem. Why do you think this could be useful?

Comment: @Neil How would 3 functions help? Did you misread all of my "general depth" and "variable depth" and "and so on" and "ad infinitum" phrases?

Comment: @aschepler For example, to perform some generic operation on a multi-dimensional "array" of arbitrary dimension (passing also the dimension, and a list of the size of each dimension). Can you think of a more natural approach?

Comment: C has no portable meta-data system built in.  Your solution requires access to a meta-data mechanism, ergo, there is no way to do this automatically.  The best way, is along the lines you describe (probably using a struct to handle the differences between pointer types).

Comment: @Neil I see. A struct is still not a solution though; don't get stuck on my illustrating 3 examples; there ought to be infinity.

Comment: @AntiEarth Do you have a more concrete example of where a construct like this would be useful to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about recursion:

```
void myfunc(void* obj, int dim) {
int* myobj1 = (int*) obj;
if (dim > 1)
{
    myfunc(*myobj1, dim-1);
}
else {
    // do stuff with myobj1
 }
```

---

On the other hand, I think you have created your own problem here, and perhaps need to ask why you need to do this in the first place.  What is the actual problem that you think this will solve?

Comment: Clever solution, though you'll need to cast to `int**` instead of `int*`, otherwise you're trying to pass an `int` to `myfunc` in the recursion, which won't compile. I've now got a new problem of making this compatible with actual multidimensional arrays (I need a deep array decay or something), but that's another story. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well no - this you can't achieve with anything other than what you showed.(You said for any level of indirection - *a nested pointer of a variable depth*). Now the more important question is why would you need that? I would say you try to organize your thoughts a bit. 3 star programmers are told to avoid this thing. (Using `***`).

One solution is to use `void*` (which you have also shown in a way) and add a parameter which will let you know inside the function what level of indirection you have. *This is the best you can do.*

Comment: To have a function, for example, accept any dimension of multidimensional array. Your proposed solution is exactly what I've demonstrated in my question, and doesn't allow an arbitrary depth.

Comment: @AntiEarth.: That's not possible - generalizing to arbitrary length. (Yours is the as close as possible trying to achieve that). That;s what is told in first line.

Answer (score 0):

There are no "nested pointers" in C.  There are pointers whose referenced data types are other pointer types, but thinking of that as "nesting" is likely to lead you down the wrong cognitive path.

But with that said, what is the problem with the approach you present?  Did you try it?  Any pointer can be converted to `void *` and back to its original type without changing its value.  This is perhaps one place where your nesting idea is leading you astray: that applies to `int *`, `int **`, `int ***` alike.  All are pointer types.  All can be converted to `void *` and back just fine.

However, having converted to type `void *`, the resulting value does not carry any information about the original type.  You need to convey that separately if you want to be able to convert back, such as you do with your `dim` parameter.

Comment: I understand pointers, and I don't see how referring to a chain of pointers as nested is misleading, nor am I the first to use the phrase. I think you've missed what I'm trying to do, since you've merely repeated the demonstrating 'solution' in my question. I'm looking to generalise the example code I gave, not understand it...